# Weird Java canvas size output

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I'm new to Java ( I have wide knowledge in JavaScript though),
I'm trying to work with `Canvas`, which leads to this weird problem.
check code [here](http://pastebin.com/5bxJrvtr). 
As you can see, After I define the size of the `Canvas`, I am trying to print it.
But it doesn't print the size properly.

```
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));

            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            System.out.println(getWidth());
```

Why the size is changed ?

Comment: Size is not changed for me if I use this example.

Comment: You can see the output which is `190`.. and the actual `WIDTH` variable is set to 180.

Comment: So how the heck I see 190 and not 180??

Comment: What is even more weird is using AWT in 2013. Start using Swing.

Comment: BTW - *"check code here."*  Most people would reply 'no thanks'.  If code is short enough to include direct to the forum, include it.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred/min/max sizes are "suggestions" to the layout managers of how your component might like to be laid out, there us no gurenttee that they will used.

A BorderLayout will try and use the available space to fill the component into,

Now, with pack, the frame's size has been set (normally) to the preferred size of the content pane.

So, now your asking, why is it not set to what it supplied. The answer is, the frame also needs to include the frame decoration, which subtracts from the usable space (frame size - decoration insets = available space) , you also need to take into consideration the menu bar